# Save image data to file while also updating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, binary

I am trying to upload an image into my database as a `varbinary` data-type.

The problem is that I also want to store the image data from a byte array into a file that exists in my solution named `TextFile.txt`. But I am not able to do so.
I want it to write the data at the same time as inserting the image into the database.

I have this code, with which I am able to insert the image into the database, but not the byte data into the text file.

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if (!this.FUImage.HasFile)
    {
        this.Label1.Text = "Please select a file to Uplaod";
        return;
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    this.FUImage.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
    var image = new Image() {
        Name = this.FUImage.PostedFile.FileName,
        FileBinary = bytes
    };
    SaveImageData(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first convert your `byte` array into `base64String` using `Convert.ToBase64String Method (Byte[])` method and then write the string to any text file.

```
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
string imageString = Convert.ToBase64String Method ();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", imageString );
```

Comment: but i am new on asp so i dont know how to write the code for writing on text file ,my code converts the data in to binary only but not able to write it on text file

Comment: wait i am trying to implement your update

Comment: You are awesome dude its working .i was trying to convert in base64 string but was not aware that how to write it on file....thanks a lot you mke my day

Comment: what to do if i want to insert the byte not base64string

Answer (score 0):

What does the method, SaveImageData, do? is it in here you're trying to wite to file?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/005f0060-09c1-4ba9-8a40-cc7fa7284320

Comment: actually i want to implement this method somewhere else so i am trying to get the image data in binary and save it on text file on the time of uploading ....any help?

Comment: You could create another method, SaveBinaryToFile() and send the bytes variable down? if you're using c# 4.x you could use the Task library to perform both tasks: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx

Comment: can you edit my code for that actually i am new on asp,i am using c#4.0

Answer (score 0):

Use binary writer to write byte data.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  
        this.FUImage.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);   
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();   
        ms.Close();   
        var image = new Image()   
        {   
            Name = this.FUImage.PostedFile.FileName,   
            FileBinary = bytes   
        };  



 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.CreateNew))  
        {
            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))  
            {  
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)  
                {  
                    w.Write(bytes);  

                }  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: can you edit my code for the purpose .